# While loop using &&

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The while loop should keep looping until both conditions are true, but it stops when only one becomes true. Why?

```
#include <iostream.h>
int main()
{
    int programsdone, result;
    cout<<"You must complete 5 programs and have a result of at least 50"<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter the number of programs completed"<<endl;
    cin>>programsdone;
    cout<<"Enter your result"<<endl;
    cin>>result;
    while (programsdone<5 && result<50)
    {
        cout<<"You need more programs or a higher result"<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter the number of programs again"<<endl;
        cin>>programsdone;
        cout<<"Enter result again"<<endl;
        cin>>result;
    }
    cout<<"congrats"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually it should keep going until one condition is **false**. Or in other words, **as long as** both conditions are true.

Comment: Should it be "the while loop should keep looping until one or two of the conditions becomes false" ?

Comment: _but it stops when only one becomes true._ That is exactly what `&&` does

Comment: Because it is AND operator.if any one of them is becomes false,it will terminate.Did you find it brain-storming?

Comment: It loops while both are `true` and stops when either becomes `false` because it was told to loop while both (i.e., `&&`) are `true`. If you want to loop while either is `true` then use `||` (i.e., logical OR).

Comment: I think you want `while(!(programsdone>5 && result>50))`

Comment: But I want it to stop when BOTH conditions become false, and I have to use the while loop, no IF.

Comment: I changed && to || and its doing what i wanted. But can someone walk me through it so its clear?

Comment: Ok. I figured it out. OR works because even if one condition becomes false, and the other remains true, the loop will continue. But when both become false, it stops. Thats what i needed.

Answer (score 1):

While loops only continue running WHILE BOTH conditions are true, not until they become true. If you want the program to stop once both conditions are true just use a negation.

```
!(programsdone<5 && result<50)
```